# Python different Requests API

Tags: python, api, request

I need to throw requests to different APIs with Python. But I have requests that take different parameters for each get request. How can I write a function that makes a request based on changed parameters?

Comment: Asking for code is off-topic in Stack Overflow.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.